# Using ConcatRelated() With 2 Where Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation, ms-access-2013

I am running this in a query - and it throws an error when I actually run the query

> Error 3061 - too few parameters.  Expected 1

And this is my syntax:

```
SELECT [ExcelImport].[unitID], [ExcelImport].Department, 
ConcatRelated('[OrderID]','[ExcelImport]','[unitID] = ' & [unitID] & ' AND [Department] = ''' & [Department]) AS [SID]
GROUP BY [ExcelImport].[unitID], [ExcelImport].[Department]
ORDER BY [ExcelImport].[unitID];
```

This is using Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() function

http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: unitID is integer, department is string

Comment: If I add triple single quotes after Department = ''' then I get a debug error of Syntax error in string in query expression - I edited my OP to reflect updated synatx

Comment: You will need to close the triple quotes after Department as well by adding `& '''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes and apostrophes must always be in pairs when used as special characters. If you find it difficult to see whether the pairing is correct, use quotes to define the argument parameters and apostrophes for the text delimiters. Need a closing apostrophe delimiter after [Department]:

```
SELECT [ExcelImport].[unitID], [ExcelImport].Department, 
ConcatRelated("[OrderID]","[ExcelImport]","[unitID] = " & [unitID] & " AND [Department] = '" & [Department] & "'") AS [SID]
GROUP BY [ExcelImport].[unitID], [ExcelImport].[Department]
ORDER BY [ExcelImport].[unitID];
```